# Hardcoding of null value in process builder

Tags: process-builder

I am working on a requirement where I have to update amount field 'A' value to zero when I update a checkbox field 'B' using a process builder. Is it a best practice to set the amount field 'A' directly to zero in the process builder if the criteria matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is [recommended practice](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_userinterface_values.htm&type=5) that you update field 'A' (or any field in your process) directly through the process builder.

Further, [zero is an integer value](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134861/how-can-i-explain-the-difference-between-null-and-zero) and is not the same as null.